# С++ - Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00502974

Tags: c++

После вписывания массива пишет - *Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00502974 в Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFDFDFE01.*
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n,b,c,d,e;
    cin >> n;
    int** a = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout.width(4);
            cout << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    e = n - 1;
    d = 1;
    c = n-1;
    b = n;
    for (int i =0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for (int j = d; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == a[b][c]) c -= 1;
            else { cout << "ne simetr" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
            }
        }
        d += 1;
        e--;
        c = e;
        b -= 1;
    }
    cout << "simetr" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка в этой части:

```
if (a[i][j] == a[b][c]) c -= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a[i][j] == a[b][c])
```

при этом `b = n` и размер массива `n x n`, т.е. `[0..n-1][0..n-1]`

а теперь угадайте куда происходит обращение по адресу `[n][n-1]` - в массив или наружу? :)